# 3 Coloumn Layout

Tags: tables, multicolumn

i would like to recreate a given PDF in the form given in the image.
My problem is that I do not know which packages have been used and would like to ask for the best way to recreate the given image.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of any packages!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
 \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\linewidth}}
   Some lines of text here \\
   Some lines \\
   Again\\
   Again some lines \\
   This is really long
 \end{tabular}
 \hfill
 \begin{tabular}{rr}
   Mobile: & 123456\\
   Office: & 98765\\
   Fax:    & 456328\\
   E-mail: &  somename@xyz.com\\
   Skype:  & flown to sky
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3360590 You are welcome.